# c# windows forms and xna - high CPU usage

Tags: c#, winforms, xna-4.0

I have an issue with xna and windows forms. I´ve developed a control with xna, and i used that control inside a windows form. My problem begins when i open a new form and it fully covers the control using xna. When that occurs the cpu usage goes to 50% or more and keeps. But if a small part of the xna control is visible the cpu usage goes down to nornal (1-10% more or less, but not more).

Here is the xna parameters configuration

```
parameters = new PresentationParameters();

            parameters.BackBufferWidth = Math.Max(width, 1);
            parameters.BackBufferHeight = Math.Max(height, 1);
            parameters.BackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Color;
            parameters.DepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.Depth24;
            parameters.DeviceWindowHandle = windowHandle;
            parameters.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.Default;
            parameters.IsFullScreen = false;

            graphicsDevice = new GraphicsDevice(GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter,
                                                GraphicsProfile.Reach,
                                                parameters);
```

Thanks in advance.

pd: it is only happening with windows xp. With windows 7 i have no problems.

Comment: I don´t know who gave a negative vote. But, i wish to know if the person has a doubt about the question or something. I don´t know, i wish a litle feedback from him

Comment: I did not downvote you, but I can understand why someone would, as your questions does not provide enough information to understand what is going on, your code won't compile, and you show no effort to fix or even understand what is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I solved the issue.
Don´t know why..but it works.

in your custom drawing code of xna at the end i just write:

```
Thread.sleep(10);
```

Comment: I doubt this "solved" the problem. If it has gone away, I suspect a race condition between threads. Investigate any synchronization or lock code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put

```
Thread.Sleep(1);
```

in your Draw() function, if you don't use a sleep command, the XNA will automatically try to run the Draw at the maximum rate, meaning that it will cannibalize one of your cores. This effectively serves as a frame limiting step. Now your computer cannot possibly render at more than 1000fps.
Using Thread.Sleep(10) limits your computer to 100fps, but if your code takes 2ms to run normally, using Sleep(10) will cut it down to 80 frames.